# AutoCompleteTextBox with icon and events

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, autocomplete, textbox

I recently managed to implement `toolkit:PhoneTextBox` with `ActionIcon`-image and `ActionIconTapped`-action into my project (*Windows Phone Toolkit*):

[image]

I need this same desing with `AutoCompleteTextBox`. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: does that need to come from DB?

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to create a custom control, which consists of `AutoCompleteTextBox` and some sort of button or HyperlinkButton. At least this is how I achieved that few months ago.

Comment: @utility Yes, from Linq-To-SQL local database

Comment: is that third party control(textbox) or custom created?

Comment: @utility It's part of the Windows Phone Toolkit (https://phone.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Do you want like this?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
       <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Width="400" Text="Search items"/>
       <Image Name="ActionIcon" Height="50" Width="50" Source="/ICommandExamples;component/Images/icon_search_text.png" Tap="ActionIconTapped"/> 
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I will try this one. The only missing property is the `Hint`, but I guess I can fix that some other way.

Comment: I am also search for water mark text in toolkit AutoCompleteBox. But no luck. If you find the solution for water mark text please let me know..!!

Comment: I came up with an idea: Make the AutoCompleteTextBox's background transparent and add a normal TextBlock behind that item. Add the hint text to this TextBlock and position it to match the AutoCompleteTextBox's text's position. Then toggle the visibility of the TextBlock according to user actions on the AutoCompleteTextView. Place the AutoCompleteTextView over the TextBlock in XAML. I quickly tested this, and it seems to work. Howerer, it takes so much time to tweak the positions and backgrounds to match...

Comment: Hi.. It will be a Good idea.. I will use this idea in my further apps if needed..!!!

Comment: I used the Hint idea and it works. I toggle the message with image's `Tap`-event and `AutoCompleteTextBox`'s `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events. Great!